# ¿Como hacer un campo relacionado entre purchase_order y stock_picking?

Tags: python, xml, odoo, openerp

Estoy intentando crear un campo date time relacionado entre el modelo **stock_picking** y el modelo **purchase_order**, sin embargo, no consigo hacer la relación entre estos, tengo entendido que el campo relación de **stock_picking** es **picking_id** y el de **purchase_order** es **purchase_id** (corrijanme si me equivoco), pero igual no me funciona.

Este es el campo en el modelo purchase_order:

```
fecha_cita_almc = fields.Datetime(related='picking_id.fecha_cita_almc', string='Fecha cita en almacén')
```

Este es el campo en el modelo stock_picking:

```
fecha_cita_almc = fields.Datetime(string='Fecha cita en almacén')
```

Como ejemplo les dejo un campo relacionado que tengo con el modelo **res_partner**

```
leadtime = fields.Integer(related='partner_id.leadtime', string='Leadtime')
```

También les dejo el error que me aparece

```
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 15.0e\server\odoo\fields.py", line 530, in setup_related
    f"Field {name} referenced in related field definition {self} does not exist."
KeyError: 'Field picking_id referenced in related field definition purchase.order.fecha_cita_almc does not exist.'
```

**EDIT**

Al final no supe como hacer la relación entre ambos modelos, pero hice una función que toma el valor de `fecha_cita_almc` **stock.picking** y lo coloca en `fecha_cita_almc` **purchase.order** relacionando el *origin* con el *name* de la orden de compra

Aunque no sé si fue la mejor opción se las dejo a continuación:

```
def _fecha_cita(self):
    self.ensure_one()

    fecha = self.env['stock.picking'].search([('origin', '=', self.name)], limit=1)
    new_fecha = fecha.fecha_cita_almc
    self.fecha_cita_almc = new_fecha
```

Comment: Hola. Los pickings se relacionan a las lineas de la purchase order. Una purchase order puede tener relacionadas varias lineas de compra  y a su vez, cada linea de compra puede tener varios pickings. De la manera que lo buscas hacer no te funcionará. Que es lo que quieres obtener de esa fecha?

Comment: En realidad solo necesitaba obtener la fecha de **stock.picking** y colocarla en el campo que se encontraba en **purchase.order**, al final lo hice con una función bastante sencilla que agrego en edición de la pregunta

Comment: Solo valida que verdaderamente necesites la fecha del ultimo picking con el origen que le pasas a la función, de otra manera podrías obtener una fecha que no sea la que buscas.

Comment: Si, en realidad necesitaba la fecha el WH/IN que se generaba al validar la orden de compra